# Solving $ \frac57(y+3)=20 $. Why don't we multiply out the brackets in this case?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi guys i'm trying to understand this problem and i've tried multiple attempts to solve it but don't uderstand the fundamentals of what is happening here.
$$
\frac57(y+3)=20
$$
At first I started by trying to -3 from both sides but this didn't produce the answer so then I tried multiplying both sides by 7 but don't understand why we wouldnt multiply the brackets by 7?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It isn’t clear just what you’re asking. If you multiply both sides by $7$, you get $5(y+3)=140$, since $7\cdot\frac57=5$.

Comment: I'm asking why don't we do 7 * y and 7 * 3?

Comment: 7 is in the denominator. Why would you multiply it by and 3, both of which are in the numerator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like unpacking a crate, the last in is the first out.  Someone took $y$ and added $3$.  THEN they multiplied by $5/7.$  So when you're unpacking, you first deal with the $5/7$. Multiply by $7/5$ to get

$$\frac{7}{5}\cdot \frac{5}{7}(y+3) = \frac{7}{5}\cdot 20$$

$$y+3 = 28.$$

Now that you cleared out the $5/7$, the path is clear for unpacking the $3$.  Subtract $3$ from both sides

$$y = 25.$$

Answer (score 3):

We can do whatever we want as long as it is consistant.

On the left hand side you have three things multiplied together. They are $m= \frac 17$ and $n = 5$ and $k=x+3$ so we have

$m\cdot n \cdot k = \frac 17 \cdot 5\cdot (x+3) = \frac 57(x+3)$.

On the right hand side we have one thing $20$.

So we have $m\cdot n \cdot k =20$

Now we can do *ANYTHING* we want to either side so long as we do to to both sides.  We can add five thousand to both side, we can take the square root of both sides, we can toss both sides into a wood chipper.

So let's say we decide to multiply both side by $7$.

So we have $7\cdot m\cdot n\cdot k = 7\cdot 20$.  That is a true statement: those four things: $7,m,n,k$ multiplied together will equal $7\cdot 20$ which is equal to $140$.

Now we can combine $7$ with any $m,n,k$ to make it only $3$ things instead of $2$.

We *could* say:

$(7m)\cdot n\cdot k = 140$.

Or we could say $7(mn)\cdot k = 140$

Or we could say $m\cdot n \cdot (7k) = 140$.

Those are all *true* statements.  ... But only one of them is useful.

$\frac 17\cdot (35)\cdot (x+3) = 140$ is a true statement.  BUt it's not useful.

And $\frac 17\cdot 5 \cdot (7x + 21) = 140$ is a true statement.  But it's not usful.

But $(7\cdot \frac 17) \cdot 5(x+3) = 140$ is a *very* useful statement.  It's useful as it cancels out the $\frac 17$ and make everything simplier.

$(7\cdot \frac 17) \cdot 5(x+3) = 140$

$1\cdot 5(x+3) = 140$

$5(x+3) = 140$.  Know if we dive both sides by $5$ we get

$\frac {5(x+3)}5 = 28$.

Now we could think of that as $\frac 55(x+3)=28$ or as $5 \frac {x+3}5=28$.  But which way is *useful*.

$\frac 55 (x+3) =28$ so

$1\cdot(x+3) = 28$

$x + 3 =28$.

Now we could multiply both sides by the square root of $13$ but that wouldn't be useful.  What *would* be useful is getting ride of the $3$.

$x+3 - 3=28 -3$

$x = 25$.

Note: as long as we do the same thing to both sides it doesn't matter what order we do things in or what we do.

I could do:

$\frac 57(x + 3) =20$

$\frac 57x + \frac 57\cdot 3 = 20$

$\frac 57x + \frac {15}7 = 20$

$\frac 57x + 2\frac 17 = 20$

$\frac 57x + 2\frac 17-2\frac 17 = 20 -2\frac 17$

$\frac 57x =17\frac 67$.

$(\frac 57x)\div 5= (17 \frac 67) \div 5$

$\frac 17 x = \frac {125}{17}\div 5= \frac {25}7 = 3\frac 47$.

$\frac 17x\cdot 7 = (3\frac 47)\cdot 7$

$x = 25$.

But that would have been very hard.

Comment: I've seen your answers, and let me reach out and say that you are being extremely instructive and detailed, it's great to see and read. I hope you receive more plaudits for your efforts in this direction, and I hope to read more content from you in the future. Thanks a lot, and +1.

Answer (score 1):

### $$\frac57(y+3)=20$$

Let's look at several solutions

\begin{align}
   \frac57(y+3) &= 20  \tag{1} \\
   \frac 57y + \frac{15}{7} &= 20 \tag{2A} \\
   \frac 57y  &= 20 - \frac{15}{7} \tag{3A} \\
   \frac 57y  &= \frac{140}{7} - \frac{15}{7} \tag{4A} \\
   \frac 57y  &= \frac{125}{7} \tag{5A} \\
   y &=  \frac 75 \cdot \frac{125}{7} \tag{6A} \\
   y &= 25 \tag{7A}
\end{align}

In (2A) you had to multiply by a fraction twice.  In (4A) you had to do fraction subtraction and in (6A) you had to do fraction multiplication. I counted fractions occurring 12 times in the above  solution.

In general, using fractions is more complicated than using integers. So the above solution is perfectly fine but it is very complicated.

Often, it's a good idea to get rid of fractions as soon as possible. What's best is, over time, you get the ability to "see" where your solution is going and to adjust your solution accordingly.

Let's look at this solution.

\begin{align}
   \frac57(y+3) &= 20  \tag{1} \\
   \frac75 \cdot \frac57(y+3) &= \frac75 \cdot 20 \tag{2B} \\
   y+ 3 &= 28 \tag{3B} \\
   y &= 25 \tag{4B}
\end{align}

In step (2B), we multiplied both sides by the reciprocal of $\frac 57$ and, in step (3B), we simplified. We "lucked out" because $\frac 75 \cdot 20$ turned out to be an integer. I counted fractions occurring 4 times in the above  solution.

I want to show you what would have happened if the $20$ was a $13$.

\begin{align}
   \frac57(y+3) &= \color{red}{13}  \tag{1C} \\
   \frac75 \cdot \frac57(y+3) &= \frac75 \cdot 13 \tag{2C} \\
   y+ 3 &= \frac{91}{5} \tag{3C} \\
   y &= \frac{91}{5} - 3 \tag{4C} \\
   y &= \frac{91}{5} - \frac{15}{5} \tag{5C} \\
   y &= \frac{76}{5} \tag{6C}
\end{align}

### EXTRA

In this case, multiplying  both sides by $\frac 75$ was a terrible idea. I counted fractions occurring 9 times in the above solution. And there was fraction subtraction and fraction multiplication going on.

So, what would have been a better thing to do? Maybe nothing. It depends on how comfortable you are with fractions. But let's at least look at an alternative solution. The reason for step (2B) was to "get rid of" the $\frac 57$ on the left side of (1B). That was a bad idea because we cleaned up the left side of the equation and messed up the right side. Just look at (3B). The solution is to be just a little bit less ambitious. Instead of getting rid of the $\frac 57$, let's just get rid of the $7$.

\begin{align}
   \frac57(y+3) &= \color{red}{13}  \tag{1D} \\
   7 \cdot \frac57(y+3) &= 7 \cdot 13 \tag{2D} \\
   5(y+ 3) &= 91 \tag{3D} \\
   5y + 15 &= 91 \tag{4D} \\
   5y + 15 - 15 &= 91 - 15 \tag{5D} \\
   5y &= 76 \tag{6D} \\
   \frac 15 \cdot 5y &= \frac 15 \cdot 76 \tag{7D} \\
   y &= \frac{76}{5} \tag{8D}
\end{align}

Notice that this is 8 steps long and the reason for that is because the solution is  a fraction. But, compare (4C) and (4D).